# Disabling "Ok Google" detection on Google Pixel 3a

Tags: google-pixel, ok-google

I wanted to start using Pixel 3a (my old Nexus 5X is outdated) but I wasn't able to disable "Ok Google". I disabled all that was possible and recommended by a few how-tos but not successful.

Did I miss something when I bought this new phone? Where can I disable this?

This question is possibly strictly connected to googles pixel 3(a)
(dont remove that from the question)

[image]

Disabled and yet, phone is allways listening and after saying "ok google" it opens a dialog.

Comment: Your Google Assistant may allow you to designate the language. Try a really obscure language, if you don't find means to disable it completely.